# Prove that linear combination of two 3D independent vector will form a plane rather than a Sold

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

How could we prove that linear combination of two 3D independent vector will always form a plane rather than a Solid?

Regards,
Tarun

Answer (score 1):

I can see two ways to answer your question.

**Definition of a plane**

A (vector) plane is by definition the set of linear combinations of two independent vectors.

**A plane doesn't contain an open ball**

It's again a question of definition. **How do you define a solid?** If you mean by a solid a subset of $\mathbb R^3$ which contains at least one open ball ("it should be able to contain some volume"), then you can prove that an open ball can't be contained in a plane.

Comment: I was having difficulty to imagine how linear combination of two vector will always form a plane in 3 dimension. Yes by definition of plane it is true that it will always form a plane